# ArangoDb Foxx joi validate unknown keys

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I am using ArangoDb 2.7.1. I am trying to implement a "flexible" Foxx Model that will have a Joi schema containing some Required and Optional attributes. In addition, I need to persist unknown keys, not defined in the schema.

Foxx model caters for the first two but adding an "unknown" (not defined in the schema) attribute always fails on model.save().

Joi itself allows unknown keys to be ignored in its validate() method (option: allowUnknown), but I can't see how to set this flag for a particular Model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joi allows defining these options on the schema itself by [using the `options` method](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v6.5.0/README.md#anyoptionsoptions).

These options should be respected during validation in Foxx.

Comment: Thank you - that will solve the problem. Much appreciated @alan